# How to use cell references(variables) inside a Query Array?

Tags: google-sheets

What works:

```
=QUERY({tab1!A3:R; tab2!A3:R; tab3!A3:R}, "select * where Col2='"&$C7&"' ")
```

What I am trying to do:

```
Cell c4 = tab1!A3:R
Cell c5 = tab name2!A3:R
Cell c6 = tab3!A3:R

=QUERY({""&$C4&"";""&$C5&""; ""&$C6&""}, "select * where Col2='"&$C7&"' ")
```

Tried all the methods of putting variables I could find without success.

Thought I just had the answer of indirect, but it only worked for the first sheet to pull in: (See answer for explanation)

```
=QUERY({INDIRECT(C4);tab2!A3:R; tab3!A3:R}, "select * where Col2='"&$C7&"' ")
```

**This does not work:**

```
Cell c4 = tab1!A3:R
Cell c5 = 'tab name2'!A3:R
Cell c6 = tab3!A3:R

=QUERY({INDIRECT(C4);INDIRECT(C5); INDIRECT(C6)}, "select * where Col2='"&$C7&"' ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INDIRECT is the working one.  Just make sure you have single quotes around your cell references that have spaces.

c4= ''tab name1'!A3:R

**Note** the single quote at the start (this was necessary for it to work as the first single quote tells Sheets that this cell is a String and removes it from the value of the cell)

```
Cell c4 = tab1!A3:R
Cell c5 = ''tab name2'!A3:R
Cell c6 = tab3!A3:R

=QUERY({INDIRECT(C4);INDIRECT(C5); INDIRECT(C6)}, "select * where Col2='"&$C7&"' ")
```